# Words whose pronunciation remains the same with the last four letters removed

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, word-games

A friend told me that the English word *queue* is the only word whose pronunciation remains the same when the last four letters are removed.

I tried to think of others, but just couldn't.  However, I don't feel this is true! (Just like when someone says [the only word without rhymes is *orange*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/282/why-does-orange-rhyme-with-almost-nothing-in-english/283#283).)

I was wondering if anyone can help?

Edit: I am going to broaden things to allow more possibilities. The shortened version does not have to be an English word. For example, *thorough* and *thoro* I feel are close enough to count as removing three letters. Also, things like *though* and *tho* definitely count! (This is the best example so far by my standards.)

Comment: Mailbox. It doesn't matter how many letters you remove, it will still be "mailbox"

Comment: @Bruno, LOL, but THWACK! nonetheless. :)

Comment: There a number words where you can remove the last three letters and and up with almost the same word: *thorough* etc.

Comment: @Jonathan:  OOoo this is good!  3 letters is start!  What other ones did you find?

Comment: @Jonathan, I don't think misspellings like *thoro* ought to count. Did you perhaps mean *though* - *tho*? The latter is an informal abbreviation, but is acceptable in certain contexts.

Comment: _[sporange](http://oxforddictionaries.com/page/442)_

Comment: @Martha: _mini-orange_, _super-orange_, _little-orange_, _super-mini-orange_... **;-)**

Comment: The words are mostly in the 'ugh' group - borough in particular (as PLL pointed out in his answer); 'thru' sorta, but the number is quite small (a single digit, I suspect). @Martha: yes, I know I'm cheating - that's why it was a comment and not an answer!  (But "thoro'" with the apostrophe to indicate stuff missing might be semi-kosher.)

Comment: @Theraot, you must have a very strange dialect. In all of the pronunciations I'm familiar with, the *a* in *orange* is unstressed and thus more or less a schwa, while *exchange* and *arrange* have the stress on their second syllables, and the *a* is thus a "long *a*". In IPA, the *a* in orange is \ə\, whereas *exchange* and *arrange* have \eɪ\.

Comment: @Marthaª A strange dialect? Kind of: I'm not a native speaker, that's my dialect... Aside from that, you are more strict. Before your reply, I didn't know there was something called "perfect rhyme"... you did encourage me to look it up, but all I've read is from Wikipedia. And since, I guess mine are imperfect rhymes.... or not even that? From my point of view, It's hard to tell without a public official set of rules to look at.

Answer (score 8):

I think your friend is probably correct. *Queue* is an example of a word that is pronounced the same way as the name of its initial letter, and while there are other examples of that, none of them are 5 letters long.

- **B** - be, bee
- **G** - gee
- **J** - jay
- **K** - 'kay
- **P** - pee, pea
- **T** - tea, tee

The other possibility would be words which have a bunch of silent letters, *and* an alternate spelling without those letters, but I can't think of any with 4 silent letters that happen to occur at the end. (For example, you can remove one letter from *colour* without changing its pronunciation.)

Edit: there's *through* - *thru*, but that removes the last two letters plus one from the middle; and *though* - *tho*, which removes three letters (and ends up with a spelling that is only acceptable in limited contexts).

Comment: I am looking for things like the words in your edit.  Though and tho is my favorite example so far!  Do you know any others?  The shortened form doesn't necessarily have to be an English word, but its pronunciation should be what you get from first reading. (Using judgment) Thanks.

Comment: How about 'meeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee!!'

Answer (score 3):

If proper names are allowed, then there are some good (3-letter-removal) examples among place-names with the suffix variously spelled *borough* or *boro*.   There are, for instance, many **Scarborough**’s and at least one **Scarboro**; several **Westborough**’s and also several **Westboro**’s; and so on.

(In the UK, *-borough* names are also often abbreviated to *-boro* on road signs.)

If we look at removing interior letters as well, then **Leicester** vs. **Lester** and **Gloucester** vs. **Gloster** are also examples.

Answer (score 1):

This has only 2 letters removed, but 'ok' and 'okay' fit the rest of the qualifications.