# Wordsmith, singer, Leonard Cohen was perplexed as what word rhymes with orange?

Tags: lyrics, rhymes, songs

My first question was basically, "What word, or words, rhyme with orange?

The word "tinge" was not included in any of the answers, or words presented to me. Thank you for your patience as a new contributor. I changed my question, citing my reason for asking a question that seemingly had been answered. I believe there is much more to add.

As quoted below, Mr. Leonard Cohen was befuddled to find a word that rhymes with orange. I wish he was was still with us, as I have answered this query of his.

My answer would be:

"The woman I long for has hair of a brilliant orange -
With a familiar scent, and beauty of a radiant tinge."

In the 'McLeans' Magazine' article - 'The heart will not retreat': How we loved Leonard Cohen'

From 2016: Brian D. Johnson on the private and permanent connections Leonard Cohen’s fans felt for him.

By Brian D. Johnson
November 16, 2016,
Second paragraph:

Leonard Cohen said in part, as quoted, "The first time we met was in a Toronto hotel, in 1992. Leonard was on a 17-country talking tour, promoting his album The Future. Speaking in finely tooled paragraphs, he described the ordeal of creating an album: “Layers of friendship fall away, and you know that you’re in it when you’re not doing anything else but trying to find the rhyme for ‘orange.’ It doesn’t exist. Some people say it’s ‘door hinge,’ but that’s not right.” As I left, he thanked me profusely, as if I had just joined his army, and I floated out onto the street feeling special. I was chagrined to see the no-rhyme-for-orange line appear in another interview, but came to learn that Leonard treated publicity as a ritual that required a polished repertoire. What mattered is that face-to-face he was so utterly present, respecting the moment as if it were as valuable as any other..."

Footnotes:

If you have interest in this article regarding Leonard Cohen, and the rhyming of the word orange, the link is: https://www.macleans.ca/culture/arts/the-heart-will-not-retreat-how-we-loved-leonard-cohen/

Comment: Hi, Campaigner! Lyrics are off-topic here, because this sort of question doesn't have one objective right answer. Do give some time to the [tour] if you haven't. Welcome, cheers!

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/283/331445 has some detail about rhyming with "orange".

Comment: I answered my own question with some deeper thought. The English language is sometimes challenging, most often, rewarding.

Comment: tinge does not rhyme with orange.

Comment: The two words 'orange' and 'tinge' are not what are referred to as a perfect rhyme. However, it is a slant rhyme. A slant rhyme consists of two words that have similar, but not perfect assonance. As well, the two rhyming words do not necessarily consist with the same number of syllables. Orange and tinge fall into the slant rhyme category.

Comment: Given that Mr Cohen was befuddled and couldn’t find a word that rhymed I would have to say that he would not accept a slant rhyme.  If he would then it would be easy.

Comment: But *orange* and *radiant tinge* aren't a perfect rhyme, because they have the stress on different syllables. It's the same reason *foresee* and *horsey* aren't a perfect rhyme.

Answer (score -1):

It just occurred to me that the following words might be right for the song's overall essence.

The next line could be: 'With that familiar scent, and radiant tinge."

I have written over thirty songs in the last year. The word orange was the hardest of words to rhyme with.